# getSupportFragmentManager returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'd like to show Google maps in my android app:

```
public class DisplayMapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private LbsTracker2 lbsTracker2;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            this.initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); // <--- always null! :(
            googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But my variable mapFragment is always null inside my method initializeMap() ...

Xml of my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lbsapp.DisplayMapActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest of my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lbsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location --> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lbsapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lbsapp.DisplayLbsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_lbs"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.lbsapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.lbsapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDnnWGwO8Zfbn5PGKXPF3aspbZTCtJ6j7I" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lbsapp.DisplayMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_map"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.lbsapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.lbsapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>    

</manifest>
```

Comment: does you app crash on launch ? can you the logs ?

Comment: Doesn't crash as it's in try/catch. No need for logs. The problem is that (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()                   .findFragmentById(R.id.map); returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was there:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Of course it has to be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the sopportMapFragment to support older version..

Example:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

SupportMapFragmentmapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it will work if you use the line you put in comments. Uncomment the MapFragment and comment the one with SupportMapFragment. MapFragment is the modern version for map fragments.

Also, in your layout try class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" instead of SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Try that change in the layout I added to my answer.

Comment: why using `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment` ?

Comment: Just noticed one significant detail. In your code you set the type of the fragment in an android:name attribute. Try class instead, without android: in front of it.

Comment: I tried MapFragment and SupportMapFragment. Both returning null. Class instead of android:name doesn't work, too.

Comment: Well, according to the documentation MapFragment is for Android versions 3.1 or newer (API 12). SupportMapFragment supports older Android versions, making it less preferable for new apps. In my implementations I set the minimum SDK version to 14, and I can always make it work with MapFragment.

Comment: I set the min sdk version to 14 now and will use MapFragment. The problem still persists anyway ... :(

Comment: Maps are nasty things in Android. I don't think this will help, but try it just in case: Click "Clean Project" from the menu "Build". Then recompile the project.