# Unable to use Toolbar with an Activity containing Google Maps Api v2

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2, android-toolbar, fragment-tab-host

I am developing an application where i need to have a toolbar at the top with bottom tabs and display Google Map in one of the tabs. I an using FragmentTabHost for the bottom Tabs and using Google Maps Api v2 for Google Maps with some custom image markers on it.I had done displaying the Google Maps on tab click but the main problem arises after this. I know for using toolbar as an Action bar i need to extend my Activity with ActionBarActivity but for using google maps i need to extend my Activity with FragmentActivity.
    I have tried a lot of things but to get a reference of Google Map in fragment i need to use this

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); 
googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
```

Now if i make my Activity extends ActionBarActivity them i will be able to use toolbar in my activity but getSupportFragmentManager() will return null as my activity was not extending FragmentActivity.Hope you guys understood my problem.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: And what about extends `FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: When i extends FragmentActivity and using Toolbar as Action bar then code setSupportActionBar(toolbar) gives a compile time error that setSupportActionBar is undefined as i have not extended my Activity with ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you check source of `ActionBarActivity` you will see that `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`. So you only need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. `ActionBarActivity` will work for you, and to make your app compatible with lower versions, you should import `android-support-v7-appcompat` in your project

Comment: Thanks Sajal for your answer. I found the real issue as i was using SupportMapFragment inside a fragment that why in the code SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); i was getting supportMapFragment as null. I found solution now i have to use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: yeah if you want fragment manager inside a fragment , you should use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 1):

`ActionBarActivity` is already [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) replace it with `AppCompatActivity`. This also subclasses `FragmentActivity`, so you can always perform all the operations as done in its parent.

Also, you can add a `FrameLayout` to your layout `XML` and then add a `Map` in it programatically, this will provide more control.

Adding in layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/region_map_container" />
```

Adding Map programmatically

```
FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.region_map_container, mapFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity already extends FragmentActivity so there is no problem here. getSupportFragmentManager() shouldn't be null. Is your setContentView OK? (Asking because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326872/getsupportfragmentmanager-returns-null)).