# findFragmentById() returns null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented Google Maps in my Android app, but i couldn't configure the map in my `Activity`. `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` returns a null value.

Here is my `pacmain_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />   

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pacientemap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`PacienteMainActivty.java`:

```
public class PacienteMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback{

private PacMainPresenterImpl pacMainPresenterImpl;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private SupportMapFragment map;
private String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
        (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pacientemap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: where you have written a sentContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity)

Comment: you forget to set view setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity);`

Without it you have nothing

Old question: [getSupportFragmentManager returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326872/getsupportfragmentmanager-returns-null)

Answer (score 4):

**setContentView** is missing Add 
 `setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity);` above  this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pacientemap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

**final code**

```
setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pacientemap);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the layout with the activity before finding content from the layout. You have to add `setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity);` Your final code will be

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pacmain_activity);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.pacientemap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```